# How to retain DVB subs in output file after encoding?

Tags: video, encoding, ffmpeg, subtitle

I have an input file which is basically a .ts file, it contains the 4 dvb subtitle streams inside of it(embedded inside). I am using the following command to retain the dvb subtitles in my output video.

```
ffmpeg -i Input.ts -c:a copy -c:v copy -c:s dvbsub output.ts
```

The output video doesn't have the dvb subs inside it.

I used the following command again to retain dvb subs.

```
ffmpeg -i Input.ts -c:a copy -c:v copy -c:s copy output.ts
ffmpeg -i Input.ts -c copy output.ts
ffmpeg -i input.ts -map 0 -c copy output.ts
ffmpeg -i Input.ts -map 0 output.ts
```

None of the above commands are working for me. 
How can I make my output.ts video to contain dvb susbs.
Regards.

Comment: Show the full log from the `ffmpeg -i input.ts -map 0 -c copy output.ts` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `-c:s copy -map 0`. The full command would look like below.

`ffmpeg -i INPUT.ts -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s copy -map 0 OUTPUT.ts`

If the INPUT.ts file has unknown data inside, then you can use the option `-ignore_unknown` after `-map 0` option.